# Can't write hyperlink as a string

Tags: c#, winforms, url, hyperlink, backslash

I want to write something like this

```
string input = "<form action=\"http://blabla.com\" method=\"post\">...</form>";
```

but the backslash() where .com ends merge with link... what i can do?

So link becoming http://blabla.com\

Comment: The example you provided is working fine for me, link is without backslash.

Comment: yes sorry... when i put mouse over link it showed me link with backslash and when I was clicking it with CTRL+Click the link was not opening because it was with backslash... didn't run it... my fault...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be more readable with strings that contain both slashes and double quotes.  It is for me.

```
string input = @"<form action=""http://blabla.com"" method=""post"">...</form>";
```

Also note that a single quote is acceptable in HTML, so this should work too:

```
string input = @"<form action='http://blabla.com' method='post'>...</form>";
```

Here's some additional info on literals in C#

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thank you I didnt know you can write like that too

Answer (score 1):

This is only visually inside the Visual Studio Editor. When running, your program should work fine.

Comment: yeah.. i should run it before posting question :/ but I learned new ways thanks  to @Chris Gessler